# US citizen working for US company in Germany

Tags: working-visas, germany, taxes, insurance

I am a US citizen and have been offered a job by a company in the US. However, they want to give me a US contract and assign me to work at the parent company office space in Germany. So I will be living and working in Germany, but will have a US contract. As an aside, I know all the upper management people in the company, have worked with them in the past, I'm not worried about them scamming me....but I'm not sure how some of this works. I have a few questions:

1. How backwards is it if they only want to pay me in US dollar?
2. At one point my contact told me I could be paid in a combination of USD and Euro, the thought being I could put the USD into my savings, and use the Euro to live off. Is this type of arrangement legal? Does it even make sense? We're talking about a job that's prob $150,000 USD/year.
3. As a US employee I would be given US insurance, and they would supplement it with international insurance. Does anyone have experience with such insurance?
4. What else am I not worrying about?

Comment: In my experience, it is more normal to have the local branch handle pay, insurance etc. They are set up to deal with taxes and other legal requirements. Any explanation of why they want to give you a US rather than German contract?

Comment: I believe you'll be liable for income taxes and the like in Germany because you will be physically in Germany while you are doing the work, regardless of the jurisdiction for which the contract is drawn up.  So the portion of your salary in euros should include the withholding for the German tax office.  If I were you I'd seriously consider consulting a German lawyer with a practice in labor law before agreeing to this.  It may depend, however, on the length of the engagement.  Is it open-ended or for a short term?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan "more normal to have the local branch handle pay, insurance etc": all the more so considering that the "local branch" is actually the "parent company."

Comment: @phoog Why just the portion paid in Euros?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan because the German tax office collects taxes in euros.  I just mean that if the salary is paid in different currencies then the euro portion should be enough to cover the German tax withholding as well as expected local expenses.

Comment: You are subject to both US and German income tax for **all of your income**, regardless what the contract says and in which currency and where the money goes into whichever bank account. You have to talk to a tax counselor which is a specialist in both US and German income tax.

Comment: @phoog: The problem is US citizens are subject to US income tax anywhere. Even if they were on Neptune. And people having their place of living in Germany are subject to German income tax. This applies to **all** of your income, even that not connected to your job. E.g. if you made 20k€ in Germany but 200k$ in the US (job+e.g leasing your empty house), you had to pay the German 45% top income tax on the 20k€. Not sure about social insurance fees and how the US handles foreign income.

Comment: @Janka most US citizens working outside the US can exclude approximately $100,000 of earned income before they calculate their US income tax ($102,400 for 2017, $104,100 for 2018).  On top of that, they can deduct tax paid to foreign jurisdictions.  So most US citizens living abroad don't pay US income tax in the end.